# String is not a function in Coffescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

i just started to learn coffeescript and it's great, but it's tricky..

i try to translate code, that worked in javascript to coffeescript

and i fail alot, in a link i posted 3 pastes

1. js.js is original code that working
2. cs.coffee is same version, but in coffeescript
3. compiled.js translated by cs compiler version of js

in translated js i got an error of "String is not a function" somewhere in a lambda that returns to map

[gist source code link](https://gist.github.com/1647212)

Comment: Your using two for loops when you could be using one :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. coffeescript's `@` is just shorthand for `this.`

So where your original js has:

```
if (input1.val().length <= 4 ...
```

your coffeescript should have

```
if   input1.val() <= 4
```

1. Where you have `$(this)` in your original js, you still need `$(this)` in your coffeescript. So

   or   @input1.map(-> this.val().match(/\s+/g)).length not 0

should be:

```
or   @input1.map(-> $(this).val().match(/\s+/g)).length not 0
```

I can't offhand see any other issues - try it and let's see if that gets it working, or if there are still errors.

**[Edit]**

There were other issues, largely related as mentioned to the `not 0` and also to bracketing. Here's a working (I think) coffeescript:

```
    if input1.val() <= 4 \
    or (input1.map(-> $(this).val().match(/\s+/g)).length != 0) \
    or (input1.map(-> $(this).val().match(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g)).length != 0)
    then input1.attr('id','error-highlight');
    else input1.attr('id','success-highlight');
```

It becomes:

```
  (function() {
    if (input1.val() <= 4 || (input1.map(function() {
      return $(this).val().match(/\s+/g);
    }).length !== 0) || (input1.map(function() {
      return $(this).val().match(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g);
    }).length !== 0)) {
      input1.attr('id', 'error-highlight');
    } else {
      input1.attr('id', 'success-highlight');
    }
  }).call(this);
```

Which looks about right.

Comment: if i  strip @ out of input1 - it says that input1 is not defined, and according to guide on official site/docs u should use @ with variables != is helping, but that's strange, coffescript.org say that "not" is same as != and != is !== ;) and i guess i really don't need extra (@input1 ...) anyway my code is half working now due to $(this) and != - i think i can fix it futher

Comment: Consider using `.any(...)` instead of `.map(...).length isnt 0`

Comment: @grncdr the method is called `some()` not `any()`.

Answer (score 9):

`.length not 0`

gets compiled into

`.length( !0 )`

Comment: @Umren I think you're looking for `.length isnt 0`. CoffeeScript compiles `isnt` into `!==`.

Comment: Because Vanilla has no place in Coffee.

Comment: I don't think the slam on CoffeeScript is helpful. Simply noting that the OP should've used `isnt` instead of `not` in this case would have been sufficient. One of CoffeeScript's strengths is that it helps *prevent* ambiguous and sloppy JavaScript, by compiling to `===` instead of `==` and checking for `null` and `undefined` etc.

Comment: Looks like pilot error to me.  Coffeescript is powerful but it's not a mind reader.